# Dynamic height of div between top and bottom div

Tags: html, css

I have structure like this:

```css
.div1 {
  display: block;
  width: 304px;
  margin-top: 83px;
  margin-left: 48px;
  margin-right: 48px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 304px;
  margin-left: 48px;
  margin-right: 48px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div2 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24px;
  height: 105px;
  width: 304px;
  margin-left: 48px;
  margin-right: 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button.item {
  text-transform: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">Dynamic Height</div>
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="item">Button 1</button>
  <button class="item ">Button 2</button>
</div>
<div class="div2">Fixed Height</div>
```

**Rules:**

1. The .div1 have dynamic height, depending on come content (could be text).
2. Then .div2 is fixed height and it is always stick to bottom of parent container (could be some other div).
3. Then button-container contain dynamic number of buttons.

How to make proper CSS, so that button-container height is always between bottom of .div1 and top of .div2, considering .div1 can change it's height?

How to make all button-items to be always in H:center W:center of the button-container, no matter how much they are?

Comment: You might want to remove `display: block` from your `div`s, since they are set to `display: block` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you remove `position: absolute` from `.div2` and use [CSS Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) as a container for your `div`s.

This allows you to place the fixed-size element at the bottom of your container without changing or obstructing the other `div`s:

```css
/* First child will have height set to 'auto', second child will have height set to 105px */
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 105px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div> <!-- This div has the height of the container minus 105px -->
        <div class="div1">Dynamic Height</div>
        <div class="button-container">
            <button class="item">Button 1</button>
            <button class="item ">Button 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">Fixed Height</div> <!-- This div has height 105px -->
</div>
```

You can also set a `min-height` to `.grid-container` to better fit the content in your web page, for example `min-height: 100vh` to fit the whole screen.

And for centering the buttons, you already did that by adding `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center;` to `.button-container`.

But I suggest you additionally add `flex-wrap: wrap`, which prevents the buttons from overflowing on the sides of the container.